# Set an image to wallpaper

Tags: android, image, onclick, wallpaper

I am new to coding and never worked with it before! We are working with Android and Java eclipse, it's a school project. Now I am working with a band application were I am supposed to create the gallery. This I managed, but to create a function were the user can set an image to a wallpaper, I couldn't. I need some help with this! I believe I found good code, but I don't know how to implement it in my work.

Does anyone know how I should connect these to each other? Really thankful for help,

Sandra

**My Gallery code:**

```
package com.Lavin;

    import com.Lavin.R;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Gallery;
    import android.widget.Gallery.LayoutParams;
    import android.widget.ImageSwitcher;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ViewSwitcher;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.app.WallpaperManager;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

    public class Lavin extends Activity implements
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
    mSwitcher.setFactory(this);
    mSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_in));
    mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            android.R.anim.fade_out));

    Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    g.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    mSwitcher.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);

}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
}

public View makeView() {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    i.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    return i;
}

private ImageSwitcher mSwitcher;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

        i.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        i.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture_frame);
        return i;
    }

    private Context mContext;

}

private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.lavin_thumb_0, R.drawable.lavin_thumb_1,
        R.drawable.lavin_thumb_2, R.drawable.lavin_thumb_3,
        R.drawable.lavin_thumb_4, R.drawable.lavin_thumb_5,
        R.drawable.lavin_thumb_6, R.drawable.lavin_thumb_7,
        R.drawable.lavin_thumb_8, R.drawable.lavin_thumb_9,
        R.drawable.lavin_thumb_10, R.drawable.lavin_thumb_11,
        R.drawable.lavin_thumb_12};
private Integer[] mImageIds = {
        R.drawable.lavin_0, R.drawable.lavin_1, R.drawable.lavin_2,
        R.drawable.lavin_3, R.drawable.lavin_4, R.drawable.lavin_5,
        R.drawable.lavin_6, R.drawable.lavin_7, R.drawable.lavin_8, 
        R.drawable.lavin_9, R.drawable.lavin_10,
        R.drawable.lavin_11, R.drawable.lavin_12};

}
```

**My Wallpaper code:**

```
package com.Lavin;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Wallpaper extends Activity {
     final static private int[] mColors =
     {Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.LTGRAY, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN,
             Color.YELLOW, Color.WHITE};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);


        Button randomize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.randomize);
        randomize.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int mColor = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * mColors.length);
                wallpaperDrawable.setColorFilter(mColors[mColor], PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(wallpaperDrawable);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        });

        Button setWallpaper = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setwallpaper);
        setWallpaper.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
                    finish();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends what language you're using, what kind of application you're writing, depends on a lot of things actually!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class LoadImagesFromSDCardActivity extends Activity implements
OnItemClickListener {

    /**
     * Grid view holding the images.
     */
    private GridView sdcardImages;
    /**
     * Image adapter for the grid view.
     */
    private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;
    /**
     * Display used for getting the width of the screen. 
     */
    private Display display;

    /**
     * Creates the content view, sets up the grid, the adapter, and the click listener.
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        // Request progress bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.sdcard);

        display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

        setupViews();
        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
        loadImages();
    }

    /**
     * Free up bitmap related resources.
     */
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
        final int count = grid.getChildCount();
        ImageView v = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
            ((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).setCallback(null);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Setup the grid view.
     */
    private void setupViews() {
        sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setNumColumns(display.getWidth()/95);
        sdcardImages.setClipToPadding(false);
        sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(LoadImagesFromSDCardActivity.this);
        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()); 
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
    }
    /**
     * Load images.
     */
    private void loadImages() {
        final Object data = getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (data == null) {
            new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
        } else {
            final LoadedImage[] photos = (LoadedImage[]) data;
            if (photos.length == 0) {
                new LoadImagesFromSDCard().execute();
            }
            for (LoadedImage photo : photos) {
                addImage(photo);
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Add image(s) to the grid view adapter.
     * 
     * @param value Array of LoadedImages references
     */
    private void addImage(LoadedImage... value) {
        for (LoadedImage image : value) {
            imageAdapter.addPhoto(image);
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save bitmap images into a list and return that list. 
     * 
     * @see android.app.Activity#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()
     */
    @Override
    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        final GridView grid = sdcardImages;
        final int count = grid.getChildCount();
        final LoadedImage[] list = new LoadedImage[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final ImageView v = (ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i);
            list[i] = new LoadedImage(((BitmapDrawable) v.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
        }

        return list;
    }
    /**
     * Async task for loading the images from the SD card. 
     * 
     * @author Mihai Fonoage
     *
     */
    class LoadImagesFromSDCard extends AsyncTask<Object, LoadedImage, Object> {

        /**
         * Load images from SD Card in the background, and display each image on the screen. 
         *  
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#doInBackground(Params[])
         */
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true); 
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            Bitmap newBitmap = null;
            Uri uri = null;            

            // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
            // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    projection, // Which columns to return
                    null,       // Return all rows
                    null,       
                    null); 
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
            int size = cursor.getCount();
            // If size is 0, there are no images on the SD Card.
            if (size == 0) {
                //No Images available, post some message to the user
            }
            int imageID = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                cursor.moveToPosition(i);
                imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID);
                try {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 70, 70, true);
                        bitmap.recycle();
                        if (newBitmap != null) {
                            publishProgress(new LoadedImage(newBitmap));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Error fetching image, try to recover
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            return null;
        }
        /**
         * Add a new LoadedImage in the images grid.
         *
         * @param value The image.
         */
        @Override
        public void onProgressUpdate(LoadedImage... value) {
            addImage(value);
        }
        /**
         * Set the visibility of the progress bar to false.
         * 
         * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
         */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Adapter for our image files. 
     * 
     * @author Mihai Fonoage
     *
     */
    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext; 
        private ArrayList<LoadedImage> photos = new ArrayList<LoadedImage>();

        public ImageAdapter(Context context) { 
            mContext = context; 
        } 

        public void addPhoto(LoadedImage photo) { 
            photos.add(photo); 
        } 

        public int getCount() { 
            return photos.size(); 
        } 

        public Object getItem(int position) { 
            return photos.get(position); 
        } 

        public long getItemId(int position) { 
            return position; 
        } 

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
            final ImageView imageView; 
            if (convertView == null) { 
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext); 
            } else { 
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView; 
            } 
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photos.get(position).getBitmap());
            return imageView; 
        } 
    }

    /**
     * A LoadedImage contains the Bitmap loaded for the image.
     */
    private static class LoadedImage {
        Bitmap mBitmap;

        LoadedImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
            mBitmap = bitmap;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return mBitmap;
        }
    }
    /**
     * When an image is clicked, load that image as a puzzle. 
     */
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {        
        int columnIndex = 0;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 

            FileInputStream is = null;
            BufferedInputStream bis = null;
            try {
                is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
                Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
                bitmap.recycle();
                //Display bitmap (useThisBitmap)
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                //Try to recover
            }
            finally {
                try {
                    if (bis != null) {
                        bis.close();
                    }
                    if (is != null) {
                        is.close();
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    projection = null;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The sdcard.xml file:

```
<GridView  
    android:id="@+id/sdcard"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />
```